# slideToggle not displaying div when screen size returns to bigger size

Tags: jquery, slidetoggle

I'm having a small, but very annoying problem!

in my CSS I have a navigation bar set up for when the screen size is above 960px. When the screen size goes below 960px the navigation bar is hidden and I display a black bar, which, when clicked, displays the main navigation bar, and hides it again, using the slideToggle() event.

My problem is that when i bring the screen below 960px, click my navigation bar open and bring the screen size above 960px again, the navigation bar returns as normal, however, if I bring the screen size down below 960px, toggle the nav bar open, then closed again, and bring the screen size above 960px, the navigation bar is missing.

What's happening is the slideToggle is still causing the nav bar to display:none even though the CSS @media rule is set to display:block when above 960px.

I tried an if statement:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

 if ($(window).width() < 960){

   $('#navcontainer480').click(function(){

     $('#navcontainer').slideToggle('slow');

   });
 }

else{

    $('#navcontainer').off('slideToggle');

}

});
```

I've also tried else ifs,  .unbind(); etc.

Maybe I'm not using them correctly.

How do I get the slideToggle to not toggle my div off when I return my screen above 960px?

Hope I made myself clear,

Thanks for the help.

Comment: the "if" is working well?

Comment: insted of slide toggle try using **slideUp** and **slideDown** in the corresponding if/else blocks. This may help you in preventing repetive unmatched toggles.

Comment: the "if" works well without the else! I'm just trying else statements to try different solutions, but it's not working. I read slideUp and slideDown were deprecated?

Comment: deprecated ?? I'm using min.js 1.8v and i'm able to use both.

Comment: Apologies, I forget where I read about slideUp and slideDown being deprecated. I was mistaken. I've used these events, but I'm having the same problem, if I slide my div down, then up again, and bring the screen size back bigger than 960px, the div remains hidden. Any suggestions on how I can remove the slide jQuery would very much be appreciated. I just need the jQuery to have no impact when the screen is above 960px! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Found the solution! I found it over at http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/responsive-web-nav/

It involves an 'if' statement declaring that if  screen width is over 960px and your div is hidden, then removeAttr('style');

My jquery now looks like so:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var navcontainer = $('#navcontainer');


        $('#navcontainer480').on('click', function(){


            navcontainer.slideToggle();


        });

        $(window).resize(function(){

            var width = $(window).width();

            if (width > 960 && navcontainer.is(':hidden')){

                navcontainer.removeAttr('style');

            }

        });


});
```

This basically says that if your div is 'hidden' because of the slideToggle when screen size is below 960px, remove this attribute when the screen size is above 960px.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Congrats!! in such a case .removeClass() would also help you in getting out the CSS(style) attribute... anyway its okay as u have done it!!